# Keras Model Cannot Deduct Shape of Input

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I am attempting to implement a Keras model for my Decoder. To do so, I have the following code:

```
def Encoder(nc_in=3, input_size=64):
    inp = Input(shape=(input_size, input_size, nc_in))
    x = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=5, kernel_initializer=conv_init, use_bias=False, padding="same")(inp)
    x = conv_block(x,128)
    x = conv_block(x,256)
    x = conv_block(x,512)
    x = conv_block(x,1024)

//RELEVANT CODE IS HERE

dense_layer = Dense(1024)
x = dense_layer(Flatten()(x))
dense_layer_weights = dense_layer.get_weights()
x = AdaptiveDropout(0.5, dense_layer_weights) (x)

//END OF RELEVANT CODE

x = Dense(4*4*1024)(x)
x = Reshape((4, 4, 1024))(x)
out = upscale_ps(512)(x)
return Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)
```

I am creating an `AdaptiveDropout` layer, which requires the **weights** of the previous layer to be able to function.

The weights are used in the `AdaptiveDropout` layer as follows:

```
def call(self, inputs, training=None):
    beta_matrix = np.ones_like(self.weights)
    pi = self.alpha * self.weights + beta_matrix
    p = sigmoid(np.tensordot(inputs[1],pi,[[None], [np.maximum(0,pi.ndim - 2)]]))
    uniform = np.uniform(p.shape)
    mask = uniform < p
    if np.mean(p) == 0:
        return p * inputs[0]
    else:
        return inputs[0] * mask
```

The problem here is that the weights as well as the inputs have an unknown shape, for example the shape for the inputs is: `(?,1024)`. The shape is only known at runtime. Therefore this code fails with index out of range. I'm not sure how to fix this problem, as I must define the model before runtime and cannot add the `AdaptiveDropout` layer later on.